# Pcap2har ignores https packets?

Tags: https, pcap, har

I use [pcap2har](https://github.com/andrewf/pcap2har) to extract from pcap to a har (HTTP Archive) file. But, when pcap file contains https packets, it ignores all the https packets.

how to avoid it? Or any other way to get har file from pcap file which containing https?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is HTTP inside a TLS tunnel. If you look at the pcap all you can see is the encrypted traffic inside the TLS tunnel but you cannot extract the HTTP requests from it to create the HAR because you would need the decrypted traffic for this.

Comment: I'm using pcapdroid to record thd pcap file and I enabled the tls derption option and I still don't get any data in the har file